# What is considered the correct way to test methods that return http observables?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I have a TypeScript project which I would like to deploy as JS NPM package. This package performs some http requests using rxjs ajax functions. Now I would like to write tests for these methods.

At some point I have a method like this (simplified!):

```
getAllUsers(): Observable<AjaxResponse> {
    return ajax.get(this.apiUrl + '/users');
}
```

I know about basic testing, for example with `spyOn` I can mock a response from the server. But how would I actually test the http request?

The documentation of jasmine says that I cannot do async work in the `it` part, but in the `beforeEach`: https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async

Would this be the correct approach to test the API?

```
let value: AjaxResponse;
let error: AjaxError;

beforeEach((done) => {

    const user = new UsersApi();
    user.getAllUsers().subscribe(
        (_value: any) => {
            value = _value;
            done();
        },
        (_error: any) => {
            error = _error;
            done();
        }
    );

});

it("should test the actual http request", () => {

    // Test here something
    // expect(value).toBe...
    // expect(error).toBe...

});
```

I couldn't think of another approach how to do the async work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mock `ajax.get` to return an Observable that emits values that you want to test.

This is done depending on how `ajax` is declared in your file that contains `user.getAllUsers` method.

It'd be ideal if `UsersApi()` had `ajax` passed into it (pure function style) because then you could just do something like this:

e.g.

```
class UsersApi {

    public ajax;

    constructor(ajax) {
      this.ajax = ajax;
    }

    getAllUsers() {
      return this.ajax.get(....)
    }

}
```

Edit: Passing in dependencies (aka dependency injection) is one thing that makes modules like this significantly easier to test - consider doing it!

Then you could very easily mock your tests out like this:

```
  const someSuccessfulResponse = ...
  const someFailedResponse = ...

  const ajaxWithSuccess = {
     get:jest.fn(() => of(someSuccessfulResponse))
  }

  const ajaxWithFailed = {
     get:jest.fn(() => throwError(someFailedResponse))
  }

  describe('my test suite',() => {

    it("should test a successful response", (done) => {

        const user = new UsersApi(ajaxWithSuccess);
        user.getAllUsers().subscribe(d => {
         expect(d).toBe(someSuccessfulResponse);
         done();
       });

    });

    it("should test a failed response", (done) => {

        const user = new UsersApi(ajaxWithFailed);
        user.getAllUsers().subscribe(null,error => {
         expect(d).toBe(someFailedResponse);
         done();
       });

    });

  });
```

Note: You **DO NOT** want to test the actual API request. **You want to test that your code successfully handles whatever API responses you think it could receive.** Think about it, how are you going to test if a failed API response is handled correctly by your code if your API always returns 200s?

EDIT #27: The above code works fine for me when I run jest, not totally clear on why jasmine (doesn't jest run on jasmine?) says it can't do async in `it`'s. In any case, you could just change the code above to set everything up in the beforeEach and just do your `expect`s in the `it`'s.